# change Initial min date in jquery datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I assigned

```
    $(function(){   
var startDate = $('#datefrom');
var endDate = $('#dateto');
startDate.datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(+new Date()-2592000000));
//***here I try to init the min date for the start date

startDate.datetimepicker({
    showSecond: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',

    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        if (endDate.val() != '') {
            var testStartDate = startDate.datetimepicker('getDate');
            var testEndDate = endDate.datetimepicker('getDate');
            if (testStartDate > testEndDate)
                endDate.datetimepicker('setDate', testStartDate);
            }
            // else {
                // endDate.val(dateText);
            // }
    },

    onSelect: function (selectedDateTime){
        endDate.datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', startDate.datetimepicker('getDate') );
    }
});
endDate.datetimepicker({
    showSecond: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',

    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        if (startDate.val() != '') {
            var testStartDate = startDate.datetimepicker('getDate');
            var testEndDate = endDate.datetimepicker('getDate');
            if (testStartDate > testEndDate)
                startDate.datetimepicker('setDate', testEndDate);
        }
        // else {
            // startDate.val(dateText);
        // }
    },

    onSelect: function (selectedDateTime){
        startDate.datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', endDate.datetimepicker('getDate') );
    }
});
});
```

to activate 1 month past dates in the datetimepicker. But still it only shows activate dates from current date.

here when initializing the plugin I set startdate min value to 1 month later. But it want work.

I use the this plugin

[Plugin on Github](https://github.com/CuriousSolutions/DateTimePicker)

Comment: https://github.com/CuriousSolutions/DateTimePicker

Comment: I have commented the link to Github please refer the plugin and tell me a way to initialize the min date

Answer (score 0):

Lets have a look at the generated date, shall we?

```
> new Date()
Sun May 18 2014 21:09:57 GMT-0700 (PDT)
> new Date(+new Date() - 2592000)
Sun May 18 2014 20:26:46 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

It looks like you are subtracting *seconds*,but  `+new Date()` converts to and `Date` expects *milliseconds*. Have a look at the [**MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). If you use milliseconds instead of seconds, it works fine.

However, a cleaner approach is to simply subtract one month:

```
var minDate = new Date();
minDate.setMonth(minDate.getMonth() - 1);
```

Comment: Sorry I subtract 2592000000 not 2592000

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this using with string format type. You can check in [MinDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate).
This is only for exact one month.

```
var date = new Date().getDate() - 1;
var minDate = '-1m-' + date + 'd';
$( '.datepicker' ).datepicker({minDate: minDate});
```

If you want only one month from today, just do like this.

```
$( '.datepicker' ).datepicker({minDate: '-1m'});
```

I hope this might be help.

Comment: As your plugin, you have to set minDate in 'dd-mm-yyyy' format. However, you set directly date object on minDate. That's why it's doesn't work. What you need to do is format your minDate.

Comment: You can easily use moment.js to manipulate date object to string format.
http://momentjs.com/